# Dart-polymer strange errors

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I am trying to create simple polymer dart application but dart editor gives me some strange errors like:

`Unexpected end tag (head). Ignored.`

`definition for Polymer element with tag name "login-window" not found.`

Here is the simplified version of that app: [git repo](https://github.com/giry/dart_test/tree/master/web)

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

In this line of `index.html`, you have misspelled `link`. As a result the parser is still looking for a closing `</ling>` tag. When it doesn't find one, it ignores the closing `</head>` to prevent improper nesting of tags.

```html
<ling rel="import" href="web_compo/login_window.html">
```